# Java: most efficient way of changing method arguments

Tags: java, class

I have a problem. So, assume there is this class native to the JRE with 100+ methods:

```
class HundredMethods {

  public void method1(int) {
  }

  public void method2(int) {
  }

  ... (98 more methods)

}
```

and I want to alter the arguments of 5 of those methods. *Specifically, integers to doubles.* **and** add an extra double argument
My current solution involves a wrapper class that:
-A: Provides direct access to the original class

-B: Has five methods that "translate" double arguments (with some extra inputs) into the integer arguments of the original. So:

```
class WrapperMethods{
   public HundredMethods original = (assigned at constructor)

   public void method1(double,double(extra)) {
     int i = (assigned a value in "code" below)
     this.original.method1(i);
   }
}
```

**Is there another lightweight solution to both changing and adding arguments to a few methods in a "heavy" class besides the one above?** In terms of actually implementing this solution in my code, I've found that it can get messy when a user doesn't know what methods the wrapper class changes. In fact, I have a roughly 250+ method class that I'm changing 25 methods of, so the bigger the class, the messier my code becomes. Considering that I want to publish my code as public, someone would have to look up what methods the wrapper changes every time they wanted to use the wrapper.

Thanks!

Comment: We could provide betteralternatife if you told us which class you want to wrap, which methods you want to change, and why they need to be changed. If it's a public JRE class, and you want to make your wrk public anyway, why not start now?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm altering the java.awt.Component class and changing any methods that deal with size or location. The reason I made my question generic is because I've only released version 0.1 of my project: [ScaleUtils](https://github.com/19mkarpawich/ScaleUtils), meaning there are most likely going to be several other UI classes that I alter methods of.

Comment: Why can't you just change the method signature from `int` to `double`? All the current call sites would work, since the `int` would be automatically widened to a `double`.

Comment: @AndyTurner my apologies, I also mean to add an extra double variable in the 5 new wrapped methods. I have updated my post to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a subclass and add in 2 methods for each of the five methods that you want to modify. One that takes a `double`, that does your logic and does a `super.` invocation to the original method, and one that takes an `int` and makes sure that it does the same thing as when you pass in a `double`.

All the other 95 methods will still be accessible through your subclass as normal.

```
class WrapperMethods extends HundredMethods {
    public void method1(double d) {
        int i = (assigned a value in "code" below)
        super.method1(i);
    }

    public void method1(int i) {
        // Make sure that any calls that happen to pass in an integer,
        // also go by your logic.
        this.method1((double)i);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. I have thought of taking your approach, but in terms of confusion (and the extra development time resulting from that confusion), what's preventing the user from accidently using the original method with the integer instead? My wrapper solution aims to deter using the original method because it requires accessing the original class before a user can access the original methods. Also, the doubles as arguments are there so the user can input decimals, so unfortunately I can't just cast an integer to a double.

Comment: @MaxK You're asking "what's preventing the user from accidently using the original method with the integer instead?" and that is specifically what my code addresses. By also implementing the method with the `int` argument, you can catch the accidental use of the original method and direct it to your `double` implementation.

Comment: So I realize now that your code makes perfect sense, my apologies. But, if you read my reply toJBNizet's comment above, my project is in version 0.1, and in 0.2 I'm adding an extra double argument to each new method. How would you go about implementing that?